# Custom typeface on buttons for lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

I have implemented my own class extending the android `android.widget.Button` class to have a custom font used in all my buttons.
To achieve this I have overridden the method `setTypeface` as following :

```
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        super.setTypeface(Fonts.get(style, getContext()));
    }
}
```

This works great in all versions of android that my app supports, except on lollipop. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I forgot to override the other definition of the method `setTypeface`. So the final working code I got is :

```
@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        super.setTypeface(Fonts.get(getContext()));
    }
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        super.setTypeface(Fonts.get(style, getContext()));
    }
}
```